# How to stop background services after logout the application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created `iPhone application` with some `Background` fetching service process for data `local notification` purpose. Now the problem is I had logout my application then It's successfully gone from home screen to `Login` screen but still now I am receiving notification, I mean still running `background services`. I want to stop all the activities from my app after clicking the logout button.

My source within `Logout button event` method

```
- (void)logoutButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Logout Clicked");
    Login *loginview = [[Login alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginview animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to cancel local notification?

Comment: Post the code on how you stop you background service? Also define background service?

Comment: Its nothing. Just NSTimer to calling evevry 10 minutes to JSON NSSerialization methode and parsing some data's. Its routine work for every n minutes. but after logout I cant stop that one.@rockoenes

Comment: why not invalidate the NSTimer when you logout? This should stop the timer.

Comment: NSTimer won't continue to execute when your app is in the background anyway, but yes, invalidate your timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its `NSTimer` `invalidate` it on logout like `[timer invalidate]`, if you already register local notifications then you can cancel them on logout like get all notifications     `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]`.

**Update:** You post notification from logouButtonAction like this `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ApplciaitonDidLoggedOut" object:nil];`
Your onlogoutbutton method should be like this

```
- (void)logoutButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Logout Clicked");
    Login *loginview = [[Login alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginview animated:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ApplciaitonDidLoggedOut" object:nil];
}
```

And in app delegate add observer for this notification in `didFinishLaunch`     `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onLogut) name:@"ApplciaitonDidLoggedOut" object:nil];`

and add method in appDelegate class

```
- (void) onLogut
{
  //considering you have a timer property in app delegate,if not add one
  [self.timer invalidate];
  // if you want to cancel local notification
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

Comment: How to stop background service into appdelegate after clicking logout button.@C_X

Comment: Canceling notification are easy you can straight away do that by copy pasting code in my answer, but for invalidating timer you need to have reference to that... In which class your timer is running...?

Comment: In appdelegate I am running NSTimer and JSON process but logout button I am placing on home screen.@C_X

Comment: why its not working, can you post ....does onLogout method in app delegate class get called on taping logout button

Comment: make sure you are posting notificaiton from logout button, I updated code again

Comment: Hi Actually I am maintaining logout button event into home screen class. timer and background processing everythig maintaining into appdelegate. First it should reffern from home class to app delegate whenever I am clikcing the logout button. notiifcation Its easy but timer not stopping. may be I want to comment "applicationDidBecomeActive" timer

Comment: you can restart timer when you after login, you can post another notification to start timer again on login

Comment: No...Sorry I am mad..what I did mean actually into applicationDidBecomeActive, there aso i wrote timer. I commented that one now its working fine. But I dont know once background to come foreground what will happen. will see thank you boss @C_X. great help.

Comment: You should check if use login or not to start and height

Comment: login control system tottaly probelem in my app. once If I click my app from background then again it will come from login. Its wrong. for example Facebook, once you logged in whenever we open its comming home only even clear background process.@C_X

Comment: You can keep session alive until user don't want to logout... and don't present login screen if user is already login, you can make that check in didFinishLaunching option and present whichever screen you want]

Comment: Yes. Once user logged into app I will store username and password into local then every time app will relaunching I need to check with some logics after logout I need to clear data into db. @C_X